# Add listView header between list

Tags: android, listview, header

This is my listView[image]

I want to add a February header on top of `2016-02-02` and January in `2016-01-31`. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is your best friend

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I thought is `addHeaderView` ?

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek Sir you want see how I populate data from MySQL to listView ?

Comment: No. `addHeaderView()` just adds **1** single View to the top of the ListView (first item). As opposed to `addFooterView()`, which adds one to the bottom (last item). Both scrollable with the items (so, not what I call REAL header and footer, which should be fixed in position).

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi expandableListView can be fixed, not expandable?

Comment: For sure, you can programmatically expand all its items. I don't know (but I wouldn't be surprised) if there's a way to let them remain expanded (possibly by setting the `setOnGroupCollapseListener()` listener and then call the `expandGroup()` method, to null the effect of a group collapse)

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi ok,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by returning a different view in your getView() method in your adapter class. In your master list, that you pass to your adapter, you can add a divider item, a String or however you are holding all this data, I assume a custom class, that you know is meant to show a Month title. You can do a quick check in your getView() method and return a different view that displays the month..

In your getView() method, you can do this...

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.times_layout, parent, false);
    Time temp = getItem(position);

    //Check to see if the time is supposed to be a header
    //This is where you check to see if it meant to be a section header
    if(temp.getDate.equals("HEADER")){
        //Header, return section view instead of normal view
        View sectionHeader = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_divider, parent, false);
        TextView txt_Section = (TextView) sectionHeader.findViewById(R.id.txt_Header);
        sectionHeader.setClickable(false);
        return sectionHeader;
    }
    //Normal View... do what you would do normally



    return customView;
}
```

I hope this helps! Let me know.. it worked for me

Comment: I assumed that your custom class is called Time

Answer (score 1):

In android It's called [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

You can try this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

It also has a sample to download.

Comment: not [this](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android)?